# How to set access permissions of google cloud storage bucket folder

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How do I set access permissions for entire folder in storage bucket? Example; I have 2 folders (containing many subfolders/objects) in single bucket (let's call them folder 'A' and 'B') and 4 members in project team. All 4 members can have read/edit access for folder A but only 2 of the members are allowed to have access to folder 'B'. Is there a simple way to set these permissions for each folder? There are hundreds/thousands of files within each folder and it would be very time consuming to set permissions for each individual file. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality and didn't see one open yet so I've created a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145082842

Answer (score 13):

It looks like this has become possible through [IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#conditions).

You need to set a IAM Condition like:
`resource.name.startsWith('projects/_/buckets/[BUCKET_NAME]/objects/[OBJECT_PREFIX]')`

This condition can't be used for the permission `storage.objects.list` though. Add two roles to a group/user. The first one to grant list access to the whole bucket and the second one containing the condition above to allow read/write access to all objects in your "folder". Like this the group/user can list all objects in the bucket, but can only read/download/write the allowed ones.

There are some limitations here, such as no longer being able to use the `gsutil acl ch` commands referenced in other answers.

Comment: I tried this, but don't seem to make it work when `[OBJECT_PREFIX]` has a slash in it, e.g. I'm don't seem to be able to allow access to files with prefix `items/1234` only `items`

Comment: I too require to restrict different users to different folders in my GCS bucket. I tried both the approaches i.e. Fine grained ACL and IAM Condition. Problem with fine grained ACL is it works only with existing objects and have to define mechanism for default ACL for objects which might added in future. IAM condition however really solves the problem of both restricting access at folder level as well as works for future objects. Additionally, it provides set of conditional operators which helps in building powerful conditional logic as require. Thank John for this answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's very poorly documented, but search for "folder" in the [`gsutil acl ch` manpage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl):

> Grant the user with the specified canonical ID READ access to all objects in example-bucket that begin with folder/:
>
> ```
> gsutil acl ch -r \
>   -u 84fac329bceSAMPLE777d5d22b8SAMPLE785ac2SAMPLE2dfcf7c4adf34da46:R \
>   gs://example-bucket/folder/
> ```

Comment: Take note of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575445/how-to-set-access-permissions-of-google-cloud-storage-bucket-folder#comment78886746_38577891 if you're trying to use this method. Brandon is correct that this does not set permissions for a "folder", but rather sets the ACL on all objects currently in the folder. New objects will have the default ACL.

Comment: @mdjnewman is correct. Does anyone know of a way to change the default ACL for new objects created in a particular folder?

Comment: @pdoherty926, have not tested myself, but I suspect you can write a cloud function that point the newly uploaded object to the acl.

Answer (score 11):

Leaving this here so someone else doesn't waste an afternoon beating their head against this wall. It turns out that 'list' permissions are handled at the bucket level in GCS and you can't restrict them using a Condition based on object name prefix. If you do, you won't be able to access any resources in the bucket, so you have to setup the Member with unrestricted 'Storage Object Viewer' role and use Conditions with specified object prefix for 'Storage Object Admin' or 'Storage Object Creator' to restrict (over)write access. Not ideal if you are trying to keep the contents of your bucket private.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam

"Since the storage.objects.list permission is granted at the bucket level, you cannot use the resource.name condition attribute to restrict object listing access to a subset of objects in the bucket. Users without storage.objects.list permission at the bucket level can experience degraded functionality for the Console and gsutil."

Comment: I appreciate your concern for our heads! This wasn't immediately intuitive, but once you explained it, makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in GCS. GCS provides permissions to buckets and permissions to objects. A "folder" is not a GCS concept and does not have any properties or permissions.

Comment: While you're right about the flat namespace (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), it does appear possible to set an ACL for a "folder" (see my answer)

Comment: That gsutil command will indeed change the ACL of every object in that path, it will not affect any future objects that are added later.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure, you have configured your bucket to have Fine-Grained Permission.
2. gsutil -m acl ch -r -g All:R gs://test/public/another/*

If doesn't work,
3. add yourself as gcs admin, legacy reader/writer permission. (which is irrelevant).
But worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2024, Google Cloud Storage managed folders are now in preview.
With managed folders, you can organize your objects into groups and set IAM policies for more granular access control over data segments within a bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managed-folders?hl=fr

Answer (score -1):

I tried all suggestions here including providing access with CEL. Then I come across why everyone is not successful in resolving this issue is because GCP does not treat folders as existing.

From https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders:

Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object named folder1/file.txt in the bucket your-bucket, the path to the object is your-bucket/folder1/file.txt, but there is no folder named folder1; instead, the string folder1 is part of the object's name.

It's just a visual representation that provides us a hierarchical feel of the bucket and objects within it.