# Google Cloud Storage - Setting unique permissions for sub folders in a bucket to different users

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to simulate a scenario - where only bucket has been created for an small company with 10 employees. Subfolders will be created within this bucket for all these 5 employees with their staff no. I do remember folders doesn't really exit, is it possible to set permission for each folder for the respective staff number? To explain it in detail - Company-A has employees with staff numbers 101 and 102. So the folders inside the bucket "buck-comp-a" will have two sub folders 101 and 102 which are their staff numbers. Is it possible to set permission for the staff with staff number 101 to read and write only his folder which is 101 and 102 should not be able to read/write the contents the folder 101 but should be able to read/write his own folder which is 102. Is this possible to achieve using Bucket ACL in google cloud storage?

Thanks
Suhas

Answer (score 0):

GCS isn't built on the concept of "folders". For details, you can see a discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575445/how-to-set-access-permissions-of-google-cloud-storage-bucket-folder). Basically, you are able to [set all files under a path at the same time](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples), but it's not the same as a folder. That means the ACL setting is an one-time deal, any future files under that path will not "inherit" the ACL; you will need to set the ACL again for the whole folder path.

So to summarize, you can set all files under a single path to a particular set of ACL, the only difference is that it will not apply to new files you upload to that path. You can get around this by adding the ACL setting code to the end of the file upload.