# Making per Service Account directories on Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, cloud-storage

I currently have a GCP bucket connected to a load balancer as a CDN for our shared hosting environment. I want to configure the GCP bucket so that each shared host can access their own directory on the bucket using a service account.

How do I configure my GCP bucket so that a service account only has write access to their own folder on the bucket.

Comment: See if the following helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575445/how-to-set-access-permissions-of-google-cloud-storage-bucket-folder

Comment: Is it a question of security on GCS or a question of routing on Loadbalancer?