# Cloud IAM Conditions for GCS objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm having problems using [Cloud IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes) to limit my service account to only have permissions to read certain files in a GCS bucket.

I'm trying to use the following condition:

```
resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/some-bucket/objects/fooItems%2f12345")
```

where I want to allow the service account to ONLY have READ access to files with prefix `fooItems/12345` inside the bucket `some-bucket`

I.e. The following files should not be authorized:

```
gs://some-bucket/fooItems/555/f.txt
gs://some-bucket/fooItems/555/foo/s.log
```

while the following files should be authorized:

```
gs://some-bucket/fooItems/1234/f.txt
gs://some-bucket/fooItems/1234/foo/s.log
```

The problem I'm having is that even files such as `gs://some-bucket/fooItems/555/*` are readable.

I tried both with and without encoded `/`, i.e.:

`resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/some-bucket/objects/fooItems/12345")`

and

`resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/some-bucket/objects/fooItems%2f12345")`

Comment: Have you checked whether the recipient of this `Cloud IAM Condition` has a primitive role `roles/owner`, `roles/editor`, `roles/viewer`.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#known_limitations. If so, the condition will not be checked.

Comment: Please, also check that the Uniform bucket-level access is activated, which is required to use the Cloud IAM Conditions https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-uniform-bucket-level-access#enable [[doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#attributes)]

Comment: @Juancki, the recipient does not have a primitive role and the uniform bucket-level access is indeed activated

Comment: Hi @simen-andresen, it seems that it could be an issue with Cloud IAM, please, try to use `resource.name == "projects/_/buckets/some-bucket" || resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/some-bucket/objects/fooItems/12345")`.

Comment: @Juancki, I got to test it now. With your suggestion, it works! However, now it seems to work even without the first condition (`resource.name == "projects/_/buckets/some-bucket"). Could it be that there was a problem with Cloud IAM Conditions that now is fixed?

Answer (score -2):

You should use [ACL's](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) instead of IAM permissions if you want to grant permission only over some of the files in a bucket. This is called [Fine grained control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)

In order to achieve this, you should change the policy of your bucket to Fine-Grained and then you can navigate to the object where you want to give permissions to the service account and add it as [documented](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl)

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I need to specify this per object? I.e. if a new object is uploaded, I need to set the ACL? Or is it still possible to define the ACL similar to using the IAM conditions (a la `name.startsWith(<prefix>)`)

Comment: You can also set [predefined permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#predefined-acl) with ACL's

Comment: I'll try that. However, from reading some more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference) and answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030302/2713641), I really get the impression that this should be possible through IAM conditions?