# Inconsistent access to subfolder of a bucket between gsutil and storage Client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

As to avoid managing a large number of buckets for data received from a lot of devices, I plan to have them write the files they capture in folders of a single bucket instead of having one bucket for each device.

As to make sure each device can only write in its subfolder, I have set the IAM condition as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030302/7505228):

```
resource.name.startsWith('projects/_/buckets/dev_bucket/objects/test_folder')
```

My service account now has the `Storage Object Creator` and `Storage Object viewer` role with the condition above attached.

This is the (truncated only to this service account) output of the `gcloud get-iam-policy <project>` command

```
- condition:
    expression: |-
      resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/dev_bucket/objects/test_folder/")
    title: only_test_subfolder
  members:
  - serviceAccount:myserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectCreator
- condition:
    expression: |-
      resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/dev_bucket/objects/test_folder/")
    title: only_test_subfolder
  members:
  - serviceAccount:myserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectViewer
```

When using the `gsutil` command, everything seems to work fine

```
# Set the authentication via the service account json key
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/my/key.json

# all of these commands work fine
gcloud ls gs://dev_bucket/test_folder 
gcloud cp gs://dev_bucket/test_folder/distant_file.txt local_file.txt

# These ones get a 403 as expected
gcloud ls gs://dev_bucket/
gcloud ls gs://another_bucket
gcloud_cp gs://dev_bucket/another_subfolder/somefile.txt local_file.txt
```

However, when I am trying to use the google storage client (v 2.1.0) I cannot manage to make it work, mainly because I am supposed to define the bucket before getting an object in this bucket.

```py
import os 
from google.cloud import storage
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="path/to/my/key.json"

client = storage.Client()

client.get_bucket("dev_bucket")

>>> Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dev_bucket?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: <Service account> does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I have also tried to list all files using the prefix argument, but get the same error:

```
client.list_blobs("dev_bucket", prefix="test_folder")
```

Is there a way to use the python storage client with this type of permissions ?

Comment: Plz list the IAM roles that are assigned to your SA.

Comment: Hey ! A specified in my question, it has the storage object creator and storage object viewer. I edited my question with the exact ouptut of `gcloud get-iam-policy <my_project>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior!

You are doing:

```
gsutil ls gs://dev_bucket/test_folder 
gsutil cp gs://dev_bucket/test_folder/distant_file.txt local_file.txt
```

Both commands does not require any additional permissions other than `storage.objects.get` which your SA has it from the role `Storage Object viewer`

**but** in your code you are trying to access the bucket details (the bucket itself, not objects inside the bucket) so it won't work unless your SA have the permission `storage.buckets.get`

this line:

```
client.get_bucket("dev_bucket")
```

will perform a `GET` method on `v1/buckets/get` which requires the above mentioned IAM permission.

So, you need to modify your code to read objects only without accessing bucket details.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object) is a sample code for downloading objects from a bucket.

note: the method `bucket(bucket_name, user_project=None)` which is used in this sample code will not perform any HTTP requests as quoted from [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.bucket).

> This will not make an HTTP request; it simply instantiates a bucket object owned by this client.

---

BTW, You can try to run something like:

```
gsutil ls -L -b gs://dev_bucket
```

I expect this command to give you the same error which you get from your code.

---

References:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-json

Comment: Although explained in the referenced answers, a reminder (to help developers with their conceptual understanding of Google Cloud Storage) that there are no folders and thus no sub-folders only Buckets and Objects. Cloud Storage [Folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This is also what I figured out from the error message. However, the guide you linked to is actually also defining a bucket object before getting a specific file. My question was then to know if there is a way to query an object directly without defining the bucket first via the Python API

Comment: You are welcome :), as I mentioned in my answer, you don't need to use the `.get_bucket()` which requests bucket details, just define the class object using the method `.bucket()` and use it in your code.

Comment: Thank you ! Your solution indeed works for uploading/downloading filenames. As this was my main pain point, I will accept this answer

However, even with the newly defined `bucket`, running `list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="test_subfolder"))` actually returns the same error. Do you have a solution for listing files ?

Comment: @LoicM Firstly, you are using the deprecated method. Recommended is to use the method `Client.list_blobs()`. See [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.list_blobs).

Comment: @LoicM The SA has the `Storage Object viewer` Role, this gives it the following 4 permissions `resourcemanager.projects.get` & `resourcemanager.projects.list` & `storage.objects.get` & `storage.objects.list`. Listing objects requires some or all of the following permissions (depending on what details you request & bucket access type) `storage.objects.list` & `storage.objects.getIamPolicy`. The SA have the first one and not the second, So you should see what details you are accessing & check access type & operations you perform and then assign the correct role/s to your SA to make this work.